# JDBC - Double Value Not Showing Up in MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, floating-point, double

I have a program that is grabbing prices from web pages, and then finds the difference of that price from the last grabbed price, and then it sends that value to my MySQL Database.

**Things to note before looking at the code:**

The actual price, which is a double, does get sent and is entered into my Database correctly, although my priceChange variable is not. I have tried changing it to a BigDecimal and that made not changes.

PriceGrabber.java  (sloppy right now, I know. I'm going to slim the code down eventually. once I get my core functions working.)

```
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;



public class PriceGrabber extends TimerTask{


    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {

            if(Coinbase.getLastPrice() ==  Variables.getCoinbase()){
                System.out.println();
            }else {
                System.out.println("Price Change Detected in Coinbase!");
                System.out.println("Price Change: " + (Variables.getCoinbase() - Coinbase.getLastPrice()));
                Coinbase.setLastPrice(Variables.getCoinbase());
                Variables.addPrice(Variables.getCoinbase(), "Coinbase", (Variables.getCoinbase() - Coinbase.getLastPrice()));

            }
            if(BTCE.getLastPrice() ==  Variables.getBTCE()){
                System.out.println();
            }else {
                System.out.println("Price Change Detected in BTC-E!");
                System.out.println("Price Change: " + (Variables.getBTCE() - BTCE.getLastPrice()));
                BTCE.setLastPrice(Variables.getBTCE());
                Variables.addPrice(Variables.getBTCE(), "BTC-e", (Variables.getBTCE() - BTCE.getLastPrice()));
            }

            if(BitStamp.getLastPrice() ==  Variables.getBitStamp()){
                System.out.println();
            }else {
                System.out.println("Price Change Detected in BitStamp Market!");
                System.out.println("Price Change: " + (Variables.getBitStamp() - BitStamp.getLastPrice()));
                BitStamp.setLastPrice(Variables.getBitStamp());

                Variables.addPrice(Variables.getBitStamp(), "Bitstamp", (Variables.getBitStamp() - BitStamp.getLastPrice()));
            }


            if(Bitfinext.getLastPrice() ==  Variables.getBitfinext()){
                System.out.println();
            }else {
                System.out.println("Price Change Detected in Bitfinext!");
                System.out.println("Price Change: " + (Variables.getBitfinext() - Bitfinext.getLastPrice()));
                Bitfinext.setLastPrice(Variables.getBitfinext());
                Variables.addPrice(Variables.getBitfinext(), "Bitfinext", (Variables.getBitfinext() - Bitfinext.getLastPrice()));
            }



            //Variables.printPrices();


        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }


}
```

Variables.java

```
       import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Enumeration;


    public class Variables {

        public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://URL TO DB";

        //  Database credentials
        public static final String USER = "username";
        public static final String PASS = "password";

    //Web Elements
    public static URL url = null;
    public static Document page = null;
    public static Element priceElement = null;
    public static Document doc = null;
    public static String price;
    public static String priceString;
    public static String timeStamp;









    //Different Market URL's
    public static String coinbaseURL = "https://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/coinbase/btcusd";
    public static String btceURL = "https://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/btce/btcusd";
    public static String bitstampURL = "https://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/bitstamp/btcusd";
    public static String bitfinextURL = "https://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/bitfinex/btcusd";



    //Sets the URL
    public static void setURL(String siteURL) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

        url = new URL(siteURL);

    }


    public static Double getCoinbase() throws IOException{

        try{
            setURL(coinbaseURL);

            page = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
            if(page.select("div.green").first() == null){
                priceElement = page.select("div.red").first();
            }else{
                priceElement = page.select("div.green").first();
            }

            priceString = priceElement.toString();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(priceString);
            price = doc.body().text();



        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(price);
    }

    public static Double getBTCE() throws IOException{

        try{
            setURL(btceURL);

            page = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
            if(page.select("div.green").first() == null){
                priceElement = page.select("div.red").first();
            }else{
                priceElement = page.select("div.green").first();
            }

            priceString = priceElement.toString();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(priceString);
            price = doc.body().text();



        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("oops! Something went wrong");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(price);
    }

    public static Double getBitStamp() throws IOException {

        try {
            setURL(bitstampURL);

            page = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
            if (page.select("div.green").first() == null) {
                priceElement = page.select("div.red").first();
            } else {
                priceElement = page.select("div.green").first();
            }

            priceString = priceElement.toString();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(priceString);
            price = doc.body().text();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("oops! Something went wrong");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(price);
    }

    public static Double getBitfinext() throws IOException {

            try {
            setURL(bitfinextURL);

            page = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
            if (page.select("div.green").first() == null) {
                priceElement = page.select("div.red").first();
            } else {
                priceElement = page.select("div.green").first();
            }

            priceString = priceElement.toString();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(priceString);
            price = doc.body().text();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("oops! Something went wrong");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(price);
    }








        //***********************************************************************************\\
        //TODO:******************************************************************************\\
        //TODO:   SEARCH FOR QUEUE SYSTEM TO AVOID HAVING TO RECONNECT FOR EACH ADDITION     \\
        //TODO:******************************************************************************\\
        //***********************************************************************************\\
    public static void addPrice(Double price, String market, Double priceChange){

        java.sql.Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            java.sql.Timestamp  sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());


            String query = " insert into prices (market, price, pricechange, time_of_change)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";


            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString (1, market);
            preparedStmt.setDouble (2, price);
            preparedStmt.setDouble(3, priceChange);
            preparedStmt.setTimestamp(4, sqlDate);


            // execute the preparedstatement
            preparedStmt.execute();

            conn.close();


        }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException se2){
            }// nothing we can do
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
    }//end main




}
```

**I'm going to show you the source of Coinbase.java, it is the exact same as the other classes (BTCE.java, Bitfinext.java, etc.) Just to save space**

Coinbase.java (Same as other market classes)

```
    /**
 * Created by Sullivan4653 on 12/8/2014.
 */
public class Coinbase {

    public static double lastPrice = 0.0;

    public static void setLastPrice(double price){
        lastPrice = price;

    }

    public static double getLastPrice(){
        return lastPrice;
    }
}
```

**Finally my MySQL Information: **

My MySQL Database/Table and columns all work except my priceChange one. The value-type is set to Double. Default value = null. That is the SAME as my price column, which seems to be working because I'm getting values of the prices. (AKA not 0 every time like my PriceChange column)

My question is, why is this double now showing in my MySQL Database? 
I apologize for the length of the post but I want to make sure I don't leave out any details that may help someone understand the problem. I've been struggling with it for a few days now and can't find the error!

Thanks!

Comment: `setBigDecimal`? if it's a double value, why do setBigDecimal?

Comment: @MarcB just realized I left that in from my last test when I made it a BigDecimal. Changing it now.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to reproduce the behavior; we don't need all your application specific code. Reducing the code might also help you find the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using static classes, go deeper into Java if you already want to make stuff like this :)

Also, if you want to provide code to others, please use some nice naming conventions, instead of making everything look like default variables (IE coinbaseURL, which should be something like COINBASE_URL, based on your modifiers).

In your code you're declaring the old value with a new value, so you're overriding it (you cannot use it anymore, because it changed to the new one).
Here's what I mean:

```
Coinbase.setLastPrice(Variables.getCoinbase());
Variables.addPrice(Variables.getCoinbase(), "Coinbase", (Variables.getCoinbase() - Coinbase.getLastPrice()));
```

I've simplified your code and improved it, this should work.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * @author JKetelaar
 */

public class PriceGrabber implements Runnable {

    private Coinbase coinbase;
    private Variables variables;

    public PriceGrabber(){
        this.coinbase = new Coinbase(0);
        this.variables = new Variables();

        this.variables.connect();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PriceGrabber(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (coinbase.getPrice() == variables.getCoinbase()) {
                System.out.println("No changes found for Coinbase...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Price Change detected in Coinbase!");

                Double cbase = variables.getCoinbase();
                Double cprice = coinbase.getPrice();

                System.out.println("Old price: " + cprice + "\nNew price: " + cbase + "\nPrice Change: " + (cbase - cprice));
                coinbase.setPrice(cbase);
                variables.addPrice(cbase, "Coinbase", (cprice - cprice));

            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {

        }

    }


}
```

-

```
public class Coinbase {

    private double price = 0.0;

    public Coinbase(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

-

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;

public class Variables {

    public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://160.153.49.168:3306/btcprogram";

    //  Database credentials
    public static final String USER = "sully";
    public static final String PASS = "asweq123e";

    //Web Elements
    public static URL url = null;
    public static Document page = null;
    public static Element priceElement = null;
    public static Document doc = null;
    public static String price;
    public static String priceString;


    public static String coinbaseURL = "https://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/coinbase/btcusd";
    private Connection connection;


    //Sets the URL
    public void setURL(String siteURL) throws IOException {
        url = new URL(siteURL);
    }


    public Double getCoinbase() throws IOException {

        try {
            setURL(coinbaseURL);

            page = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
            if (page.select("div.green").first() == null) {
                priceElement = page.select("div.red").first();
            } else {
                priceElement = page.select("div.green").first();
            }

            priceString = priceElement.toString();
            doc = Jsoup.parse(priceString);
            price = doc.body().text();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(price);
    }

    public void addPrice(Double price, String market, Double priceChange) {
        /**
         * In your table set the time of change to a default value, so the table will do the time itself.
         * Makes it easier for you and doesn't get complicated if you want to get others to insert prices.
         */
        this.query("INSERT INTO prices (market, price, pricechange) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", new Object[]{
                price, market, priceChange
        });
    }

    public ResultSet query(String q, Object[] args) {
        if (connection == null) {
            System.out.println("No connection to the database.");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(q);
            for (int i = 1; i <= args.length; i++) {
                if (args[i] instanceof Double){
                    preparedStatement.setDouble(i, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(args[i])));
                }else{
                    preparedStatement.setString(i, String.valueOf(args[i - 1]));
                }
            }
            if (q.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
                return preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            } else {
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://160.153.49.168:3306/btcprogram?"
                            + "user=sully&password=asweq123e");
            if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully connected to the database...\nReady for SQL queries!");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```